# Can I use an excel file twice in one Talend job?

Tags: excel, salesforce, talend

I'm trying to upload data from an excel spreadsheet into Salesforce with Talend. The Excel spreadsheet has multiple sheets, which I can access through different schemas. The opportunites input works, while the accounts input does not, even though I'm using the same input filepath of `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))`.

[image: Screenshot of Talend job]

How can I restructure my job so that I can correctly use the Excel sheet twice?

Comment: Have you considered a step that pulls the data out of each sheet and keeps them in separate files/database tables?

Comment: How exactly does the `Iterate` of `t_FileList_1` pass the file name information to `Oppotunities Input`? In a context variable? If so, could you use the same?

Comment: Another thought: Maybe it's a race condition. Apparently, the second Excel input does not have any prerequirement, so it can start instantly at the beginning of the job. At that point of time the first input job may not have the filename defined yet. Somehow you have make both Excel input components dependant on the iterate component.

Comment: @MarcusRickert, both of the excel inputs use ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH")) in their filepath/data stream. I think the iterate command simply defines the flow of control, but does not affect what files the input uses.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I could do this, but then it would increase the complexity by a generous amount. I think the job would have to keep track of multiple files and then use them, which I'm unsure how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marcus Rickert hit the nail on the head with [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261750/can-i-use-an-excel-file-twice-in-one-talend-job#comment39361179_25261750), you've created a race condition as the lookup data is loaded at the start of the subjob.

There's a couple of solutions to this:

As per [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261750/can-i-use-an-excel-file-twice-in-one-talend-job#comment39360830_25261750), you could have an intermediary step that stages the data by pulling the data out of the file and then making that accessible to your job in a way that doesn't rely on your lookup being defined by a globalMap variable that is only defined after the lookup should be started.

Or, by far and away the easiest way but potentially impacting on performance, you could just change the lookup model in the tMap to use "Reload at each row". This will make it reload your entire resource every row coming in from the main which will obviously have some performance issues but they may be marginal or not a problem for you. My test job ran through several iterations of a dozen lines each in pretty much the same time as the default "load once" lookup model. This will probably be O(N) though so it depends on your data volumes.

You can find the lookup model option the join settings of the tMap:

[image: lookup model in tMap]

Comment: I changed the Lookup Model to Reload at each Row, and it worked! Thank you kindly, @ydaetskcoR and Marcus Rickert.